# K-mean on multiple KPI fields

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, k-means

I am new to Machine learning. My question can be very basic. I got a k-mean trained model, this model is based on 6 KPI fields. I have a dataset of 6 KPI, I successfully used predict method and created cluster using pkl file. I have few questions after reading few blogs -

1. Is it advisable to develop k-mean model using 6 KPIs?
2. I am trying to add visualization that depict cluster and centroid but  not able to decide which chart I can use for all these 6 fields. Which chart I can use for visualization?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share any code here, and that's fine, in this case at least.  I believe you would do something like this.

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# etc., etc.

data = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Feature1']),np.asarray(df['Feature2'])])
# etc., etc., etc.
# run a few experiences using 2-6 KPIs. 

# computing K-Means with K = 5 (5 clusters)
centroids,_ = kmeans(data,5)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
```

Does it make sense?  Check out the link below.  I think this guy explains the concept very well.

https://www.pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/